# Return HttpResponse object and render page from Django views.py

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and have been learning by modifying some existing code. The original code, in the views.py file, had a method that returned an HTTP Response object (lets call this `resp`) to the browser, on the click of a button.

I want to be able to

1. open a new page on a click of that button (which I am doing using the render() function)

as well as

2. pass `resp` to it (this is because the 3rd party API that I am using needs this `HttpResponse` object in order to work).

Is there anyway I can do this? I thought of passing `resp` as part of the `context` parameter in the `render()` function, but I don't understand how I can collect back the value from this `context` dictionary and then return it to the browser.

EDIT: This is the code in the views.py file:

```
def call(request):
    """Returns TwiML instructions to Twilio's POST requests"""
    response = Dial(caller_id=settings.TWILIO_NUMBER)

    # If the browser sent a phoneNumber param, we know this request
    # is a support agent trying to call a customer's phone
    if 'phoneNumber' in request.POST:
        response.number(request.POST['phoneNumber'])
    else:
        # Otherwise we assume this request is a customer trying
        # to contact support from the home page
        response.client('support_agent')

    response = str(response)
    probe = response.find(">")
    response = response[:probe+1] + "<Response>" + response[probe+1:] + "</Response>"
    print('response:', response)
    context = {'response': HttpResponse(response)}
    return render(request, 'browser_calls/call_in_progress.html', context)  # originally HttpResponse(response) was being returned here because that was required for the call to be placed
```

Comment: `open a new page on a click of that button` do it on the front, it should not be done by back end.

Comment: There can't be any way a third-party API needs the Django HttpResponse, so clearly something is being confused here. You should show the code you have that calls the API.

Comment: So where in this code do you have the third-party API requiring the Django HttpResponse?

Comment: @BearBrown the onclick functionality is specified in the js file. In Django, I thought that the views.py communicates to the browser as shown here: https://ibb.co/G3NP81k

Comment: @DanielRoseman the Dial feature is something they have implemented for which they need me to return an HTTP response object to the browser. And I think what is happening with the Dial object (whichis passed as a response) is that it is being used to finally make a call

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is return all the variables from that scope using locals()

```
context = locals()
return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: If the problem is giving the response to the front-end, putting locals() as a context may solve it

Comment: Thanks! Would I also have to append the `resp` object somewhere here?